# PHP LDAP Windows 2008r2 Change users password

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2008-r2

I've got here an Windows Server 2008r2 set up with Active Directory, DNS, DHCP and DC for testing purposes and i am quite new to LDAP.

I want to change the password for myself, even though if i am no
   admin.

So, here is my script i am working on right now:

```
// LDAP Variables
$serverip = "192.168.2.1";
$serverport = 636;
$username = "user";
$userpassword = "password1";
$newpass = "password2";
$userDn = "CN=$username,CN=Users,DC=dc-name";

$ldapconn = ldap_connect($serverip, $serverport) or die("LDAP Connection Failed!\n");
ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
if ($ldapconn) {
    echo "Connection succeded\n";
    // LDAP Bind
    $bindresult = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $username, $userpassword);
    if ($bindresult) {
        echo "Bind: Succeded\n";
        $userData['unicodePwd'] = toPwEntry($newpass);
        $modresult = ldap_mod_replace($ldapconn, $userDn , $userData);
        if (!$modresult) echo "PW Change Failed - Error No. ". ldap_errno($ldapconn).": " .ldap_error($ldapconn) . "\n";
    }
    else echo "Bind Failed - Error No. ". ldap_errno($ldapconn).": " .ldap_error($ldapconn) . "\n";
}
else echo "Connection failed - Error No. ". ldap_errno($ldapconn).": " .ldap_error($ldapconn) . "\n";    

function toPwEntry($pw) {
    return("\"". iconv('UTF-8','UTF-16LE',$pw) ."\"");
}
ldap_close($ldapconn);
```

when i start the script i get this error:

```
soenke@work:~/Desktop/$ php ldap.php
Connection succeded
Bind Failed - Error No. -1: Can't contact LDAP server
```

i also tried connections by using "ldaps://" in front of the ip but it doesn't work.
i would appreciate any help!

Comment: Check if your AD server is listening on port 636

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions:

`ldap_bind()` wants `$userDN` rather than `$username`.  That would cause a different error message though.

There's no actual network traffic between your web server and the ldap server until you call `ldap_bind()`, so make sure there aren't any firewall/network issues, etc.  The error message says "Can't contact the server"; that might be exactly what's happening.  (The `ldap_connect()` function just initializes a local struct in later versions of ldap libraries. You could think of it more like "ldap_init()" -- the "Connection succeeded" message doesn't imply a successful network connection here.)

You can setup an LDAP server to handle both secure and insecure connections on 389 instead of 636.  Make sure you're connecting where the server expects you to.

These symptoms might also show up if your end of the TLS connection fails to verify the server certificate.  You either have to provide root certificates to trust, or configure your client to not verify the cert (if the server has a self-signed certificate, for example).  Either of those can be accomplished by setting variables in an ldap.conf file.  Where to put ldap.conf depends on your web server setup.

This: http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/tip/5838.html and this: http://www.whatsnoodle.com/php-ldap_bind-gives-the-error-cant-contact-ldap-server/ might have more details for you.

Answer (score 0):

Active Directory will only let you change passwords via LDAPS and I'm pretty sure you have to use port 636.
When you specify LDAPS:// try it in upper case.  At least one of the MS provider monikers is case-sensitive.  I'm not completely sure it's the LDAP one; I've used caps for all monikers for years.
Your password, I think, has to be an octet string (byte array).  I can't read PHP so I can't tell if that's what you're doing but I'm guessing so.
Your domain controller will need a certificate to do LDAPS.  I'm no certificate expert but I think the name you use for the server has to match the one on the certificate and it's not normally the IP address (though I think you can put them in alternate names on the cert) so I think you should be using the server name.